# I'm integrating the function $z(x^2+y^2)$ over a sphere in the first octant$ x,y,z\geq 0$ (solved)

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

I'm trying to solve this problem in different coordinates, but I get different answers. Here's what I've managed to set up:
In Cartesian coordinates:
$$ \int_{0}^{8} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{64-z^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{64-y^2-z^2}} z(x^2+y^2)\, dx dy dz$$

In cylindrical coordinates:
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{8 }\int_{0}^{\sqrt{64-z^2}} z\rho^{3}\,d\rho dz d\theta  $$

In spherical:
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \int_{0}^{8 } r^{5}\,\sin^{3}(\phi)\cos{\phi}\,dr d\theta d\phi $$
My calculator gives 4096π for the Cartesian coordinates, I get $(4/3) 4096π$ when I use cylinderical or spherical coordinates and my calculator agrees with me on those. Did I set them up wrong? I read the chapters on these topics like thrice and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, this is fairly simple problem. Pls help ;-;
(I didn't do Cartesian one with hand, I'll try it and see what happens). Okay I miscalculated, it's solved now. Thank you math lover.

Comment: Which one gives you a wrong answer? I am not clear.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know which one is wrong.

Comment: I feel like the Cartesian one is correct because it seems like a nice number

Comment: None of them are wrong. You should get the same values for all integrals.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I miscalculated.

Comment: Yes you may have miscalculated. $\frac{16384 \pi}{3}$ should be the answer.

Comment: In Cylindrical coordinates, you may change the order and integrate wrt $z$ before $\rho$. It may be easier calculation.

Comment: Okay thanks I did it by hand and I got the right answer. My calculator was probably trolling me.